# Entity Framework only save single record from the list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to insert a new record from `TPOSTransaction` and `TPOSTransactionDetail`

The code below is from an event in my class:

```
_posTransaction = new TPostransaction();
_posTransactionDetail = new TPostransactionDetail();
_posTransactionDetails = new List<TPostransactionDetail>();

_posTransaction.UserId = _user.Id;
_posTransaction.Total = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOrderTotal.Text);
_posTransaction.ChangeDue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtChangeDue.Text);
_posTransaction.AmountPaid = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmountPaid.Text);
_posTransaction.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;

foreach (ListViewItem orders in lvOrders.Items)
{
   _posTransactionDetail.ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(orders.SubItems[1].Text);
   _posTransactionDetail.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(orders.SubItems[3].Text);
   _posTransactionDetail.Subtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(orders.SubItems[4].Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(orders.SubItems[3].Text);
   _posTransactionDetails.Add(_posTransactionDetail);
}

    _posTransaction.TPostransactionDetail = _posTransactionDetails;
    _pos.Add(_posTransaction); //method from a class
```

This is where I save the record:

When I try to debug, `POSTransaction.TposTransactionDetail` have 2 records since it's what I added from the list

```
//this is my primary concern
var posTransaction = dbContext.TPostransaction.Add(POSTransaction);
dbContext.TPostransactionDetail.AddRange(POSTransaction.TposTransactionDetail);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This saves the record of TPosTransaction and TPosTransactionDetail, but the detail that is being saved is only one, instead of 2. I tried removing the `AddRange` part it still saves a single record in my `TposTransactionDetail`.

Comment: instead of `_posTransactionDetail = new TPostransactionDetail();` at top, declare TPostransactionDetail in every iteration of foreach loop.`foreach (ListViewItem orders in lvOrders.Items) {var details = new TPostransactionDetail(); ...... _posTransactionDetails.Add(details);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on you foreach you need to create new instance of TPostransactionDetail, you are just reusing the instance on the top of your code.

Comment: and add it manually to a separate context for TPostransactionDetail?

Comment: because I was thinking if there's a way where I can do a single SaveChanges for all, and why is AddRange not working?

Comment: ef SaveChanges is a unit of work. It will save as a Unit, you just have to create multiple instance and add it on your dbset

Comment: my pleasure kabayan